# How Can I Restrict User To Select Only One Checkbox?

Tags: android, android-studio, checkbox

I am creating a voting system for android and I want to select only one `CheckBox` - [see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JdsFw.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `RadioButton` within `RadioGroup` instead of `CheckBox`.

But if you really, really must use `CheckBox`, you can do it with listeners:

```
checkBox1.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener{
    onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked){
        checkBox2.setChecked(false);
    }
});
checkBox2.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener{
    onCheckedChanged (CompoundButton view, boolean isChecked){
        checkBox1.setChecked(false);
    }
});
```